# Flip 2 Modal ViewControllers Back and Forth

Tags: ios6, storyboard

For an iPad app using storyboards, I have 3 ViewControllers.  One is full screen (let's call it 'rootScreen'), and the other two are both 300x300 (we'll call them 'frontSide' and 'backSide').  If, from 'rootScreen', I segue to show a modal 'frontSide', how can I flip from 'frontSide' to show 'backSide', and vice-versa?  Kind of like flipping a flash card back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose `UIModalTransitionStyle` while presenting a view controller modally. So when you present your 'FrontSide' view controller from your 'RootScreen', while presenting the 'BackSide' view controller from there, you can set the `modalTransitionStyle` property of view controller to `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal` and then present it. When you'll dismiss the 'BackSide', it will dismiss using the reverse flipping animation itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Zen.  But wouldn't that keep 'frontSide' visible while 'backSide' flips in over top of it?  i want to have 'frontSide' and 'backSide' simulate their flipping similar to holding a flash card and flipping it back and forth over top of the 'rootScreen'.

Comment: Hmm..If you set the 'backSide's `modalPresentationStyle` property to `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` then 'backSide' and 'frontSide' will appear like a card is flipping over. But it leaves the context in there while flipping. You can play with properties like `definesPresentationContext` and `providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle` though to see if you can get rid of the white(or empty)context.

Comment: Please refer to this [Apple documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)